# You flip a coin $n$ times. What is the probability that there have been twice as many tails as heads?

Tags: probability

> You flip a coin $n$ times. What is the probability that

> a) There have been exactly 3 heads

$$ {n \choose 3 } \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^n$$

> b) There have been at least 2 heads

$$1-\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^n- n\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^n$$

> c) There have been equal numbers of heads and tails

$$ { n \choose n/2 }\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^n 
n \text{ }\text{ even}.$$

> d)  there have been twice as many tails as heads?

I can not seem to find this problem on here. Let us denote $p$ for probability of heads (I know they are equally likely).

$$n = 1: P(T = 2H) = 0 : \{\}$$
$$n = 2: P(T = 2H) = 0 : \{HH,TH,HT,TT\}$$
$$n = 3: P(T = 2H) = {3 \choose 2}p(1-p)^2$$
$$ : \{HHT,THT,HTT,TTT, HHH,THH,HTH,TTH\} $$
$$n = 4: P(T = 2H) = 0 $$

I am really struggling with this one. I have included other parts of the question just incase they are relevant.

Comment: If you interpret "head" as "success" and $H$ denotes the number of heads then $H$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p=\frac12$ (provided the coin is fair) and are asked to find $P(H=\frac13n)$. The probability can only be positive if $n$ is a multiple of $3$ so it might be handsome in go for $n=3m$.

Comment: How is this conceptually any different than the "equal numbers of heads and tails" question?  For choosing equal number you chose $n/2$ of the $n$ positions.  For this, just choose $n/3$ of the positions from the $n$ positions.

Comment: Hint: to say "twice as many tails as heads" is the same as saying "2/3 are tails" and "1/3 are heads"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part (d) only makes sense if $(n)$, the number of coin flips, is a multiple of $(3)$, and is therefore expressible as $3k$.

Then, the number of Tails will be twice the number of Heads if and only if there have been exactly $(k)$ Heads in the $(3k)$ coin flips.

The probability of this happening is

$$\binom{3k}{k} (1/2)^k (1/2)^{2k} ~: ~n = 3k$$

$$= \frac{\binom{3k}{k}}{2^{(3k)}}.$$